# Having trouble implementing multilingual umbraco 3.0

Tags: umbraco, multilingual

How to implement the multilingual umbraco 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

There are two different approaches to this.

The documentation on the Umbraco website describes how to do 1:1 multingual sites. This means that you have one site structure and different language tabs in a single document type for each translation od the content. This is then selected by using an on page selector on the website (a flag icon or the like).
[Here's an example of a 1:1 site](http://www.arn-swords.com/frontpage.aspx)

This is the most efficient set up if you have lots of shared content i.e. the content and structure is exactly the same, the language is just different.

The second approach is to use separate page structures for each language, such as:

International Homepage

------> English Homepage

------------> English content page

------> French Homepage

------------> French content page

The advantage of this structure is that it is very easy to set up, but if you share lots of content it can be cumbersome to manage. It also has the advantage that you can lock the editing permissions down for country/language specific editors.

With the above structure you can also point individual URLs to the country pages.

Without knowing more about what exactly your requirements are it's hard to answer more fully as to which is the best approach. It may also be possible to create a hybrid solution.

Here are some links which may help:

http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst2209_Multilingual-structure-in-umbraco.aspx

http://www.nibble.be/?p=32